# Is there a way to write a Jinja set nested within a Jinja for loop

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I am currently using Jinja within DBT to create these three sets which all work fine:

```
{% set value1 %}
    select
            category1,
            category2,
            category3,
            category4
        
        from {{ ref('table') }}
        where category1 = 'value1'
        order by category2
    
{% endset %}

{% set value2 %}
    select
            category1,
            category2,
            category3,
            category4
        
        from {{ ref('table') }}
        where category1 = value2
        order by category2
    

{% endset %}



{% set value3 %}
    select
            category1,
            category2,
            category3,
            category4
        
        from {{ ref('table') }}
        where category1 = value3
        order by category2
    

{% endset %}
```

I am wondering if there is a way I can condense the creation of those three sets by using a for loop.

This was my attempt at doing so:

```
{% set attributes = ('value1', 'value2', 'value3') %}


{% for i in attributes%}
    
    {% set {{i}} %}
    
        select
            category1,
            category2,
            category3,
            category4
        
        from {{ ref('table') }}
        where category1 = {{i}}
        order by category2
    
    {% endset %}
    
{% endfor %}
```

I keep running into errors regarding the first line of the set within the for loop. I have attempted writing it several ways with syntax changes within the for loop but nothing has worked.

I am wondering if I can recreate the output of the three sets in anyway which would be more condescend then having to write out all three sets?

Answer (score 1):

Your use case seems a perfect fit for a [macro](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#macros):

Define your macro:

```
{% macro get_set(value) %}
  select
    category1,
    category2,
    category3,
    category4
  from {{ ref('table') }}
  where category1 = {{ value }}
  order by category2
{% endmacro %}
```

Then to use it:

```
{{ get_set('value1') }}
{# and #}
{{ get_set('value2') }}
{# and #}
{{ get_set('value3') }}
```